# Mouse hold in wxWidget

Tags: wxwidgets

I have w graph made in wxWidget. I'd like to enable moving it by holding the left button. My idea is to catch all the mouse events, move the graph after the down click and escape the function after the up click. Do you have any better ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You only need to handle `wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN` and `wxEVT_LEFT_UP` mouse events. Inside the `wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN` handler, test for `event.Dragging()`

Comment: The user will appreciate that you force a redraw of the graph in its new location each time the mouse drags, and also in the left-up event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [CaptureMouse()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.1/classwx_window.html#a5c72c6260a73ef77bb0b1f7ec85fcfef) to do this. Don't forget to call `ReleaseMouse()` later and, importantly, also handle mouse capture lost event (see the documentation link above), as your program can always lose capture unexpectedly, e.g. if the user switches to another application.

Comment: `CaptureMouse()` is useful if you intend to move the graph out of its window, into another window. Is it also needed if movement only happens inside its window?

Comment: It is, if only to cancel the move when the capture is broken. Generally speaking, any mouse operation involving more than one mouse event should capture mouse.